# Click event does not persist for new dynamically created elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code that attaches to the click event of a class:

```
$(".filter-link").click(function (e) {
    $("#filter").dialog("option", "position",
                    { my: "left top", at: "left bottom", of: e });
    $("#filter").dialog("open");
});
```

The element I use it on is dynamically recreated often:

```
function addTopLinks() {
    $('#calendar .fc-view thead th.fc-resourceName')
        .removeClass('top-calendar-cell');
    $('#calendar .fc-view thead th.fc-resourceName')
        .addClass('top-calendar-cell');
    $('#calendar .fc-view thead th.fc-resourceName')
        .html('<a class="filter-link" href="#">Filter Resources</a>');
};
```

Is there any way I can get the click to persist or will I be forced to reassign the click every time I recreate the element?

Thanks

Comment: It's a duplicate of MANY questions! The answer is using `.on()` correctly will work. Does not need writing out in full again

Comment: @Pointy they removed .live... That's an old answer. The question I posted is recent, .on has replaced .live and others.

Comment: Ah OK - well hopefully somebody else will find a better one; there must be thousands of such questions out there :-)

Comment: some time `delegate` function is useful for your problem. see http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$(document).on("click", ".filter-link", function (e) {
     $("#filter").dialog("option", "position",
            { my: "left top", at: "left bottom", of: e });
     $("#filter").dialog("open");
});
```

Comment: Again, please don't answer duplicated questions -_-